# How do you get a process id in java?

Tags: java, process, terminal

I am trying to find a way to programmaticaly open and close an application. I can launch the application easily using

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"open", "<path to application>"});
```

however, the only way I can find to close it is to use the line

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"kill", "<process id#>"});
```

and I can't find anyway to get the id # other than manually opening terminal and using top to find the #. If there is a programmatic way to get this id, or just a better way to go about opening and closing applications i would love to hear about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to start the subprocess.  The returned [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object has a `destroy()` method which will let you kill it.

Comment: This works fine to start the application, but it keeps running after I have called destroy()

Comment: Is the subprocess trapping and ignoring signals? (I assume you're on *nix and not Windows based on the wording of your original question).  Also, what are you running in the subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't relevant anymore to the original poster (due to the elapsed time) but just for the sake of completeness...

You get a handle to the process object as a result of the `exec(...)` command:

```
Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mybin");
```

You can then kill at any later time with `destroy()`:

```
myProcess.destroy();
```

Note: This might be similar to what Jim was describing but not using the `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` has been around for a long time now.  Use it unless you have good reasons for *not* doing so.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You're indeed right ;-). `getRuntime().exec()` is something I used on the past that I know to work, but `ProcessBuilder` is the way to go as a general rule.